# C++: inheriting functions and redefining them

Tags: c++, function, inheritance, parent-child, virtual

I am having some problems with interfaces, inheritance and redefinition. In this case I am not sure why exactly C++ behaves like this, so if someone could explain and help me with this. I have this classes:

module.h:

```
class mixer;

class module {

public:

  module(std::string name_) : name(name_) {}
  ~module() {}

  virtual module& bind(module &mod) = 0;
  virtual module& bind(mixer &mix) { return ((module&)mix); }

  std::string get_name() 
  {
    return name;
  }

  std::string name;
};
```

in_out.h:

```
class in_out : public module {

public:

  in_out(std::string name_) : module(name_) {}
  ~in_out() {}

  virtual module& bind(module &mod)
  {
    std::cout << "bind in_out in " << mod.name << std::endl;
    return mod;
  }

};
```

prod.h:

```
class prod : public in_out {

public:

  prod(std::string name_)
    : in_out(name_)
  {}

  ~prod() {}

  virtual module& bind(mixer &mix)
  {
    std::cout << "bind mixer in " << get_name() << std::endl;
    return mix;
  }

};
```

mixer.h:

```
class mixer : public in_out {

public:

  mixer(std::string name_)
    : in_out(name_)
  {}

  ~mixer() {}
};
```

So, if in my main file I have this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  prod  prod1("prod1");
  prod  prod2("prod2");
  mixer mixer1("mixer1");
  mixer mixer2("mixer2");

  prod1.bind(prod2);

  return 0;
}
```

I get this error:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
main.cpp:12:19: error: no matching function for call to ‘prod::bind(prod&)’
main.cpp:12:19: note: candidate is:
prod.h:19:23: note: virtual pfn_module& prod::bind(mixer&)
prod.h:19:23: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘prod’ to ‘mixer&’
make: *** [main] Error 1
```

If I have this instead:

```
prod1.in_out::bind(prod2);
```

It works as expected.

What I do not understand is, shouldn't the compiler distinguish between these?

```
virtual module& bind(module &mod) = 0;
// and
virtual module& bind(mixer &mix) { return ((module&)mix); }
```

I guess the problem could be that both `mixer` and `prod` are child of `module` (and `in_out`). Maybe when the function `bind` is called in main, it looks for it in the definition of `prod` and only finds `bind(mixer)`? What about `bind(module)`? Is it private in that context?

What I would like to have is, no matter what I call `prod.bind(prod)` or `prod.bind(mixer)`, it distinguishes them at `prod`'s level, so I don't have to call `.in_out` from there.

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that when you defined class prod and declared function bind

```
virtual module& bind(mixer &mix);
```

in the class scope you hided all other functions with the same name of the base class. So then you called

```
prod1.bind(prod2);
```

the compiler sees only one candidate in the class scope: the function shown above. And it can not convert reference prod to reference mixer.

You should write in the class definition

```
using in_out::bind;
```

And  as **@Alex** pointed out in his comment you have to make the destructor of class module virtual if you use polymorphism.

EDIT: If to substitute pfn_inout for in_out because there is no definition of pfn_inout then the following code is compiled successfuly

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class mixer;

class module {

public:

  module(std::string name_) : name(name_) {}
  ~module() {}

  virtual module& bind(module &mod) = 0;
  virtual module& bind(mixer &mix) { return ((module&)mix); }

  std::string get_name() 
  {
    return name;
  }

  std::string name;
};

class in_out : public module {

public:

  in_out(std::string name_) : module(name_) {}
  ~in_out() {}

  virtual module& bind(module &mod)
  {
    std::cout << "bind in_out in " << mod.name << std::endl;
    return mod;
  }

};

class mixer : public in_out {

public:

  mixer(std::string name_)
    : in_out(name_)
  {}

  ~mixer() {}
};

class prod : public in_out {

public:
    using in_out::bind;

  prod(std::string name_)
    : in_out(name_)
  {}

  ~prod() {}

  virtual module& bind(mixer &mix)
  {
    std::cout << "bind mixer in " << get_name() << std::endl;
    return mix;
  }

};


int main() 
{
  prod  prod1("prod1");
  prod  prod2("prod2");
  mixer mixer1("mixer1");
  mixer mixer2("mixer2");

  prod1.bind(prod2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Also made the destructors of base classes virtual.

Comment: Ok. Makes a lot of sence :) But I'm getting this error:

`error: ‘virtual module& in_out::bind(module&)’ is inaccessible`

Comment: @makeMonday I do not know what is pfn_inout in your example. I think it is in_out. If so then Your example when main contains only these three statements   prod  prod1("prod1");
  prod  prod2("prod2");

  prod1.bind(prod2);
is compiled successfuly.

Comment: Yes, that was the original name, I changed for a simpler one, but in this question was a typo. Anyway, I was having some linking issue. Now is working fine! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

In C++, name lookup stops in the scope where the name is found.
(There are some exceptions, linked to ADL, but they don't apply
here.)  The reason for this is to avoid changing the semantics
of functions in your derived if names are added to the Base
class.

Typically, this shouldn't be a problem, because you should
implement all of the virtual functions in an interface in all of
the derived classes.  And virtual functions and non-virtual
functions shouldn't share names.  In your case, what you
probably want in the base class is something like:

```
class Module
{
private:
    virtual Module& doBind( Module& mod ) = 0;

public
    Module& bind( Module& mod )
    {
        //  pre-conditions
        Module& results = doBind( mod );
        //  post-conditions and invariants
        return results;
    }
    Module& bind( Mixer& mix )
    {
        //  pre-conditions
        Module& results = doBind( static_cast<Module&>( mod) );
        //  post-conditions and invariants
        return results;
    }
};
```

Derived classes will implement their own versions of `doBind`,
but nothing else.

One thing, though.  The conversion `(Module&)mix`, in a context
where the compiler cannot see the full definition of `Module`,
is a `reinterpret_cast`, which is almost certainly *not* what
you want.  I used `static_cast` in my example, to align with
what you've done, but it is, in fact, illegal if the compiler
cannot see the definition of `Module`.  In this particular case,
in fact, there is no need what so ever for the second `bind`
function, since `Mixer&` will convert implicitly to `Module&`,
without the need for a conversion on your part.  (But it's quite
possible that this code is just a very simplified example, and
that in your real code, you're actually doing something more
complex.)